# Pink Anthurium in apartment - leaves turning brown and dying

Tags: watering, indoors

I've been keeping 3 plants of pink anthurium in my apartment - bought at different points of time from different shops, all plants initially healthy. All three however end up showing the same symptoms: leaves start turning brown at the tip, eventually killing the leaf. The plant themselves sprout new leaves but quite slowly, with a lot of "stumps." Moreover, some young leaves already have brown tips (see photos).

I try to water them once or twice weekly (although I tried changing the regime and doing it once weekly) and spray them every 2-3 days but it doesn't seem to help.

One more data point: the apartment doesn't get *a lot* of sunlight.

Am I treating the plants wrong? Please help!

[image: Plant 1]

[image: Plant 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is difficult to say as some of the more obvious problems are not apparent:

- I don't see any sign of scale or thrip
- the portions of the leave that are browning do not look like they have a fungus or virus
- no signs of nutritional deficiency

I suggest that over watering might be the cause.

- provide more light
- ensure good drainage
- water thoroughly and let the top inch of the medium dry

Comment: Thanks. I'm considering putting one of the plants into Misco Self-watering Planter, which apparently prevents over-watering. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Brown tips like that are caused by the oils from people or animals touching them. If you have animals, move them out of reach, and if you handle the leaves a lot, stop.

Comment: Interesting idea, any references for it?